# Notification list erroneously lists a downvote twice when changing the question title

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

After changing the title of my question the downvote that I had gotten on the question was duplicated in the notification list.  It appears as if the question was downvoted twice, but there is only one downvote on the question when visiting it directly.

[image]

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 9.3.3 (Build 13G34)

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in 1.6.5.4.

The achievements dialog in the app has been updated to exactly match the top bar.